# Swift Soundboard App

Tags: swift, tableview, viewcontroller, appdelegate

Hi I am a beginner programmer using swift who is trying to create a basic soundboard template. My code has been getting signal SiGABRT in the AppDelegate and I have no idea why. Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code and or provide me with the code I could use to create a soundboard. This is what I have so far for my ViewController, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Class SoundListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var soundsArray: [Sound] = []
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var audioNSURL = NSURL()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    let samplePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RandomSound", ofType: "m4a")
    audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(samplePath!)!
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioNSURL, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    var soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RandomSound1", ofType: "m4a")
    var soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)
    var sounds1 = Sound()
    sounds1.name = "Sound1"
    sounds1.URL = soundURL!
    self.soundsArray.append(sounds1)

    soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RandomSound2", ofType: "m4a")
    soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)
    var sounds2 = Sound()
    sounds2.name = "Sound2"
    sounds2.URL = soundURL!
    self.soundsArray.append(sounds2)

    soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RandomSound3", ofType: "m4a")
    soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)
    var sounds3 = Sound()
    sounds3.name = "Sound3"
    sounds3.URL = soundURL!
    self.soundsArray.append(sounds3)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.soundsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.soundsArray[indexPath.row].name
    println(cell)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var sound = self.soundsArray[indexPath.row]
    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.URL]

    var rowSoundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!


    if audioPlayer.playing && rowSoundURL == audioNSURL {

        audioPlayer.stop()

    } else {

        audioNSURL = rowSoundURL

        self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioNSURL, error: nil)
        self.audioPlayer.play()

    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple mistake in your code ;-) In the viewDidLoad()-method you just set the soundURL variable to the full path of the media file (in that case to RandomSound1.m4a and so on)

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath()-method of the table view delegate you do the following:

```
var sound = self.soundsArray[indexPath.row]
var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.URL]
```

and then

```
var rowSoundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!
```

and that is the part, where the app crashes. This happens because the the NSURL-class tries to create a URL (like defined in RFCs 1808, 1738, and 2732) depending on baseString and sound.URL. If you check these to variables, it will look like the following:

```
sound.URL => "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D30CB30-919A-4253-AEFD-7386ED63A553/soundboard.app/take_5.m4a"

baseString => "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63ADE8EB-DAE0-49E0-83A7-88378F675F9D/Documents"
```

so when you now combine these two variables, the path is in wrong format and it leads to crash. Instead, you can just use sound.URL, and it will do what you want.

I implemented it that way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var sound = self.soundsArray[indexPath.row]
        var baseString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

        if let rowSoundURL = sound.URL {
            if audioPlayer.playing && rowSoundURL == audioNSURL {

                audioPlayer.stop()

            } else {

                audioNSURL = rowSoundURL

                self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioNSURL, error: nil)
                self.audioPlayer.play()

            }
        }
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Note: In my case, the URL variable of Sound is optional. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new to coding and would really love to get an app out there. When I implemented your code,  there was  an error saying "bound value in a conditional binding must be of optimal type." When i took out the first if statement so that it just had: 
let rowSoundURL = sound.URL {
there was an error saying "Cannot invoke URL with an argument list of type (0 ->_). " I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: You're welcome! On which line does the error appear? I use XCode 6.3.2 and I think it uses Swift 1.2. 

Actually my Sound object looks like this:


    'import Foundation
    class Sound: NSObject {
 var name: String?
 var URL: NSURL?
}'


If you still habe problems, just show me how your Sound object looks like, so I can update my code

Comment: I also have the same Sound.swift object. Xcode gives me an error on the let rowSoundURL = Sound.URL { line saying that Sound.type does not have a member named URL even though I am pretty sure it does. As well the if audioPlayer.playing && rowSoundURL == audioNSURL { and  audioNSURL = rowSoundURL come up with the error variable used within its own initial value. I am guessing this is because the rowSoundURL is not working properly but I am not 100% sure.